# Excel VBA Macro Graphing Dynamically

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an excel file that opens automatically then it runs a macro. This macro imports data from a txt file. Every 1 hour, data goes into the txt file into a new row (time stamp and a value). My macro at 5pm opens up, imports the data, graphs it, saves it to a dynamic date, then closes.

This macro opens up once per day at 5pm. However, I dont want the macro to keep selecting the first 24 rows on the first day and the second 24 rows on the second.
when it runs on the second day. On the second day, I would like to only select rows (25-49). On the third day, I would like to select rows ( 50-74).

Does anyone have a method about dynamically selecting rows using the same macro?

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'
' Auto_Open Macro
'

'
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\LOGTEST.txt", Origin _
        :=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote _
        , ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=True, Comma:= _
        False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 1) _
        ), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Columns("A:B").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'LOGTEST'!$A:$B")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    myFileName = "myFile_" & Month(Now) & "_" & Day(Now) & "_" & Hour(Now) & "_" & Minute(Now)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\" & myFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your time stamp in the text file include a date? If so I may have an answer.

Comment: It includes a date and time. Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Const F_PATH As String = "C:\_stuff\"
Dim wb As Workbook, sht As Worksheet, rng As Range
Dim cht As Chart, myFileName As String

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=F_PATH & "test.txt", Origin:=437, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:= False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 4), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(1)
    Set rng = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

    'just use the last 24 rows...
    If rng.Row >= 24 Then Set rng = rng.Offset(-23, 0)
    Set rng = rng.Resize(24, 2)

    sht.Columns(1).EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(Top:=100, Left:=100).Chart
    cht.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    cht.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

    myFileName = "myFile_" & Month(Now) & "_" & Day(Now) & _
                   "_" & Hour(Now) & "_" & Minute(Now)
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=F_PATH & myFileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    wb.Close savechanges:=True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in memory instead of bringing it into a spreadsheet:

```
dFirstDate = #10/1/2013#
dDate = Now
nDays = DateDiff("d", dDate, dFirstDate)
nRowStart = nDays * 24
sFile = "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\LOGTEST.txt"
Open sFile For Input As iFileNum
Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
While Not sBuf = "" And Len(sBuf) > 1
    nFileRow = nFileRow + 1
    If nFileRow >= nRowStart And nFileRow <= nRowStart + 24 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(nSheetRow, 0).Value = sBuf
        nSheetRow = sSheetRow + 1
    End If
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
Wend
Close #iFileNum
```